# How do I cancel a delayed action if the same button that triggered it is clicked before the delayed time is executed?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class viewcontroller1: UIViewController {
```

I have these two images. When the next button is clicked, image1 changes to image2 after 10 seconds. However, I have no idea how to cancel/reset the delayed action if the next button is clicked again before the 10 seconds has expired. This is the code I have so far...

```
var image1: UIImageView!
var image2: UIImageView!

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

@IBAction func nextbutton(_ sender: Any) {

image1.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
delay(10) { self.image2.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
}
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: use timer and reset timer every time when action called

Comment: Since you are using `anyncAfter` you can't cancel the action.  As Mike said, use a `Timer` which you can cancel via `invalidate`

Answer (score 0):

`anyncAfter` can  not be canceled

As per comment you have to use `Timer` following is example

Create global  variable

```
var timer:Timer?
```

and On action

```
@IBAction func btnImageChangedTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (self.timer != nil) {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil;
    }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: yourTime, target: self, selector: #selector(changeImage:), userInfo: sender, repeats: false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried to use this but am unsure how to add the image change into the code, I tried... timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(image1.image = UIImage(named: "image1")), userInfo: sender, repeats: false)

Comment: You need to create `changeImage` Method , it will execute after 10 sec and change image in that

Comment: At the moment I don't have enough reputation. But I will definitely come back to this question when I do, you saved me hours!

Answer (score 0):

u can try this one

var timer : Timer?

```
    func startTimer(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.YourImageChangeAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func resetTimer(){

    timer?.invalidate()
    startTimer()
}
```

add func resetTimer to your UiButton sender.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a click counter in your VC and test it upon execution of the delayed code.

for example:

```
var clickCount = 0
@IBAction func nextbutton(_ sender: Any) 
{
   clickCount += 1
   let wantsClickCount = clickCount
   image1.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
   delay(10) 
   { 
     guard self.clickCount == wantsClickCount
     else { return }
     self.image2.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
   }
}
```

if the button was clicked again before the closure executes, the clickCount will no longer match and the timed code will do nothing.

This would even work with very fast clicking.  Note that it will push off the image change by 10 seconds each time so the image change will always happen 10 seconds after the last click.